# Graphical logviewer that auto reload when file changes?

Tags: logs, gui, tail

I'm wondering if there's a graphical viewer, also it needs to support auto-reloading when log file has changed.

ksystemlog doesn't reload automatically.

Comment: Do you mean that it should swing over to the new file when `logrotate` is called, as opposed to staying on the original fd?

Answer (score 1):

Might it be the [`root-tail`](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/root-tail.html) utility satisfies your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually happy with `less +F log_file` for monitoring events.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -F log_file | xrootconsole`
where `-F` is a shortcut for `--follow=name --retry`

You can also use conky, with the variable
`tail logfile lines (next_check)` in `.conkyrc`. From the manpage:

> Displays last N lines of supplied text file. The file is checked every 'next_check' update. If next_check is not supplied, Conky defaults to 2. Max of 30 lines can be  displayed,  or  until the text buffer is filled.

Note that if you are using linux, `tail -f` actually waits for the kernel to notify that the file^Wdescriptor has been modified. Not sure about `tail -F`, but conky is a bit overbloat if you don't need anything else than reading a log file.